# foward rolling window self defined function python

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a data frame in python 3 looks like this, it has a time stamp on its index. I want to conduct a forward rolling window of 10 seconds.

[image]

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [25,4,2,33,44,88,51,29,18,42]})
 df.index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:01'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:10'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:17'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:22'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:45'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:53')]
```

For each observation, i want to find observations within the next 10 seconds and preform some analysis with a self defined function. My functions is as follows:

```
def logsum(data):
    series = pd.Series(data)
    return 2*(np.log(data.max()) + np.log(data.min()))
```

Basically find the series and calculate the sum of the maximum and minimum 's log values.

I try to reverse the series then perform the normal rolling window analyses, it now has two problems. 1. it can not conduct my logsum function; 2. the series needs to be monotonic: "ValueError: index must be monotonic"

my current code is:

```
df['B-roll'] = df[::-1].rolling('10s').A.logsum()
```

Here is the expected output:

[image]

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [25,4,2,33,44,88,51,29,18,42], 'B-roll':   [4.49,4.49,4.49,6.92,7.17,7.3,6.33,5.84,5.75,6.49]})
   df.index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:01'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:10'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:17'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:22'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:45'),
         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:53')]
```

For example df['B-roll'][0] is 4.49. For the next 10 seconds, the maximum 'A' is 88, minimum 'A' is 2. so, logsum function finds =2*(LOG(88)+LOG(2)) = 4.49.

The rest follows,
Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your expected output for this data? Does `df.resample('5s')['A'].apply(logsum)` work for you?

Comment: @coldspeed, just made edits to show the expected output. df.resample('5s')['A'].apply(logsum) does not seem to give the expected results.

Comment: Based on your output, that would mean the first period is 11 seconds long. That doesn't make sense, right?